# c# anonymus functions as aparameters

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates, anonymous-function

i'm currently starting with c# and want to use anonymus functions to interact with fields (two dimensional arrays). What i want to achieve should look somehow like this.

```
//...somewhere in class
private int[][] field1;

interactWithElements(field1, {
  x++;
  //...more complex stuff
});

private void interactWithElements(int[][] field, 
                                  Func anonymusFunction(int x)) {
  for (int x = 0; x < field.Length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < field[0].Length; y++)) {
      anonymusFunction(field[x][y]);
    }
  }
}
```

Is something like this possible in c#? And when it is, how can i do this?
Maybe with delegates?

Thank you alredy.

Comment: I think there is a small bug with your loop, you may have meant `field[x].Length` instead of `field[0].Length`

Comment: doesnt make any difference in my code the field is always a perfect rectangle, otherwise other code could would catch the problem ;)

Comment: Cool fair enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there:

```
//...somewhere in class
private int[][] field1;

interactWithElements(field1, x => {
  x++;
  //...more complex stuff
});
```

What you have defined up there is a lamda expression `x => { x++; }`, see this [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687(v=vs.110).aspx) for information on it.

The rest only needed the correct parameter.

```
private void interactWithElements(
    int[][] field, 
    Action<int> anonymusFunction) 
{
  for (int x = 0; x < field.Length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < field[0].Length; y++)) { // <- you may have meant x instead of 0
      anonymusFunction(field[x][y]);
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to define some inline function that returns you something look at [`Func<T, TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you're happy without returning something then use [`Action<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx)

As a side note, you can specify quite a lot of input parameters with these delegates, but too many can get real confusing!